# How to perform Lexer Actions that send an Exception?

Tags: antlr4

I'm new to ANTL4 and I can't seem to figure out how to get lexer actions to perform properly.

I have a code snippet that looks for input text:

`SIZE10 : [a-zA-Z]* {getText().length() <= 10}?`

I would expect that it does not match any combinations of letters that are over 10 letters long, however what this does is treat a 10+ letter string as two different tokens, instead of just nullifying the whole set of 10+ letters. How can I get this action to nullify the whole set of letters?

In addition, where can I go to see all the different token functions I can use (other than getText())? The documentation about lexer actions is really poor. In general, I'm having a hard time figuring out what resources can give me a definitive list of everything in the language. Even an entry point into the source code for me to read would be good at this point. The documentation is too general/basic for me.

EDIT: I've figured out how to send a RuntimeException, but I don't know where to get the elements needed for a proper RecognitionException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate in a rule directs the parsing process in a way that allows to match only partial input (like in your case) or essentially switch off a part of the grammar depending on certain conditions. In your case the SIZE10 rule is matched until the predicate returns false. Everything up to this event is then returned as a match for SIZE10. After that lexing continues at the point it ended for the previous token and if that is again a letter it will again match SIZE10 as long as the predicate says it is correct. That's a bit different than what you would expect (e.g. using the predicate as an all or nothing switch).

However, if you instead want to match the full set of letters first and then check if the length is <= 10 you can do this in a listener. You can hook into the exitSIZE10() event and reject the match by throwing a recognition exception.

For the usable functions in your actions see the API documentation for ANTLR. For instance [here is the one for Token](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Token.html) which shows you other possibilities beside getText(). In your action, consider the context you have. In a lexer rule you deal with a Token, hence getText() etc. work on the token. In a parser rule you have a ParserContext instead, which also has a getText() function but that works differently (collecting all child contexts text into a comma separated list).

Comment: How do I create a listener for a lexer? I'm not familiar with how to "hook into" the exitSIZE10() event.